# is there a way to define a directive in postgresql to filter all records in a database?

Tags: postgresql

I have a database in postgres with data of different owners and I'd like to create a directive to filter the data according the user.

For example

```
table invoices
--------------
owner   date       amount
01      2022-10-2  5000      
01      2022-10-3  50
07      2022-10-2  543
05      2022-10-9  1
```

What I ask is when a owner login to the system only can see his data, not the data of the other owners.

All the tables have the owner field.

thanks!

Rodolfo

Oracle has directives to filter data to some profiles.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Postgres **Row Security Policies**.
Row-level security (RLS for short) is an important feature in the PostgreSQL security context. This feature enables database administrators to define a policy on a table such that it can control viewing and manipulation of data on a per user basis. A row-level policy can be understood as an additional filter; when a user tries to perform an operation on a table, this filter is applied before any query condition or filtering, and data is shrunk down or access is denied based on the specific policy.

Reference
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html

https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/how-implement-column-and-row-level-security-postgresql